# react-sizeme doesn't measure height of component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am using react-sizeme in order to measure the height/width of a `Content` component from ant design. Here is my code:

```
 <SizeMe render={({ size }) => {
            if (size.width == null && size.height == null) {
              return <Content></Content>
            } else {
              //Content contains a lot of HTML, so I only want to fully render it after the inital size has been determined
              return <Content>Width: {size.width} Height: {size.height}</Content>
            }
          }} />
```

However, `size.height` is undefined/null. Why is the height not being measured, and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you wrapping `Content` correctly with `withSize`?

Comment: Am I supposed to? The github page indicates that you can use the render prop pattern: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme, so I thought you don't need to wrap `Content`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `SizeMe` won't track the height. You can fix this by adding `monitorHeight`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { SizeMe } from "react-sizeme";

function App() {
  return (
    <SizeMe
      monitorHeight
      render={({ size }) => {
        return <h1>I am {size.height}px tall!</h1>;
      }}
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You can see the available options on the Github repo [here](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-sizeme#configuration).

Comment: Oh whoops, I tried using that prop before, I didn't realize you are not supposed to do `monitorHeight={true}`. How can you pass in a prop without explicitly setting a value?

Comment: If you pass just e.g `someProp`, React interprets it as being `true` :) Not sure why `monitorHeight={true}` wouldn't work however, maybe it was something else.

Comment: That still doesn't work for me, because height is not getting updated when resizing window!